# How to achieve an exclusive connection with FireDAC SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

When `FDConnection` is using the `SQLite` Driver it has a `LockingMode` property that is set to `Exclusive` by default. However, this does not seem to work as expected.

When running the below code, an error does not occur when opening the second connection:

```
  FDConnection1.Params.Database := DB_PATH;
  FDConnection1.Open();

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'update admin set last_write = 2';
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;

  FDConnection2.Params.Database := DB_PATH;
  FDConnection2.Open();
```

Specifically setting the SQLite pragma for Exclusive locking mode also does not seem to work:

```
  FDConnection1.Params.Database := DB_PATH;
  FDConnection1.Open();

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE';
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'update admin set last_write = 2';
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;

  FDConnection2.Params.Database := DB_PATH;
  FDConnection2.Open();
```

Again, no error on opening the second connection.

How does one effect an Exclusive locking mode when opening a SQLite database? Why does setting the `PRAGMA` manually not work?

**EDIT**

After further testing, I see that opening a second connection with a different component set e.g. UniDAC or ZeosLib, does in fact result in an error.

However, no error occurs when opening a second FDConnection or even writing to that connection. It seems like FireDAC connections are in some way shared no matter what..

Comment: What ecactly do you mean by "not work"?  That the connection works but does not prevent other apps using the db, or what?

Comment: "no error on opening the second connection." Also, no error when performing a read/write with second connection either.

Comment: I don't think a SQLite 'engine' is created by FireDac for each connection to local databases (files).  Shared engine means shared exclusive access. Not sure if there is way to force it to use another engine, perhaps using a FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1.

Comment: "Shared engine" - where does it say it is a shared engine?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of the EXCLUSIVE lock.

from the [SQLite 3 documentation](https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) it is:

> An EXCLUSIVE lock is needed in order to **write** to the database file.
>   Only one EXCLUSIVE lock is allowed on the file and no other locks of
>   any kind are allowed to coexist with an EXCLUSIVE lock. In order to
>   maximize concurrency, SQLite works to minimize the amount of time that
>   EXCLUSIVE locks are held.

this lock is requested only when trying to write to the database file. (see: *5.0 Writing to a database file*)

To confirm this I made a simple test with SQLiteStudio and a simple Delphi application where I instruct the SQLiteStudio to add 1 million records and try to add one with the Delphi app. I always get a Firedac error `Database is locked.`

Comment: It's not clear what kind of exclusive mode you are using in SQLiteStudio. "this lock is requested only when trying to write to the database file." Correct, that is why I perform a write in my code sample. Also no error occurs when writing to the db with the second connection.

Comment: @RaelB All write operations require the EXCLUSIVE lock. I used SQLiteStudio because I know it is written in c++ and QT (non firedac solution). The point of the test is to confirm the quote above that only one EXCLUSIVE lock is permitted when writing.

Comment: @RaelB read the linked documentation. you will see the locks required to write to the database file. firedac as any other solution out there needs to confirm to the specification in the documentation.

Comment: You'll get the error by just setting the `TFDConnection.Connected` property to `True`  at design time, and then run your application, and try to perform an action, you'll find that the db is already locked. There is no need to have SQLite Studio to do so.